# JMM: Synchronization order and InterruptedIOException

Tags: java, multithreading, java-memory-model

The Java Language Specification incorporates the Java Memory Model specification. In [JLS 1.7.4.4, "Synchronization Order"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4), the following is said about interrupting Threads:

> If thread `T1` interrupts thread `T2`, the interrupt by `T1`
>   *synchronizes-with* any point where any other thread (including `T2`)
>   determines that `T2` has been interrupted (by having an
>   `InterruptedException` thrown or by invoking `Thread.interrupted` or
>   `Thread.isInterrupted`).

Would "determining that `T2` has been interrupted" include "having an `InterruptedIOException` thrown"?

The language of the first sentence suggests that it does. But then the text within the parentheses suggests that it exhaustively lists how it can be determined that a thread has been interrupted, and `InterruptedIOException` is not in that list.

It would be great if an answer could be backed up by a reference to an official clarification or to a quote from one of the authors of the JMM.

Comment: InterruptedIOException, AFAIK, is a higher-level IO Exception that is itself thrown when the thread has been interrupted, i.e. when the IO method throwing it has itself detected thanks to interrupted(), isInterrupted() or InterruptedException that the thread has been interrupted.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--